# for loop in a while loop not working in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

i'm trying to make this some more compact:

```
while (res->next())
{
    strcpy(laArray[i][1],res->getString(1).c_str());
    strcpy(laArray[i][2],res->getString(2).c_str());
    strcpy(laArray[i][3],res->getString(3).c_str());
    strcpy(laArray[i][4],res->getString(4).c_str());
    strcpy(laArray[i][5],res->getString(5).c_str());
    strcpy(laArray[i][6],res->getString(6).c_str());
    strcpy(laArray[i][7],res->getString(7).c_str());
    strcpy(laArray[i][8],res->getString(8).c_str());
    i++;
}
```

i've come up with this but it aint working: (it freezes at startup)

```
while (res->next())
{
    for (int j=0; j < 3; j++){
        strcpy(laArray[i][j],res->getString(j).c_str());
    }
    i++;
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: And _'but it aint working:'_ means what exactly? Edit your question to elaborate please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop has the wrong initial and ending values

```
while (res->next())
{
    for (int j=1; j <= 8; j++){
        strcpy(laArray[i][j],res->getString(j).c_str());
    }
    i++;
}
```

Also, I'd look very closely at why you are using 1-based indexing rather than 0-based which is the idiom in C++: the first element of an array is at index 0.

Comment: Wait what... it actualy worked... but why do they give me the wrong code on this tut... http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/ and in my c++ class i also did learn to use (int j=0; j < 3; j++) this way.

Comment: Try putting `!= 8` in there, that even better.

Comment: Try shifting your values:
for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)